# in app billing - how to test another currency

Tags: android, in-app-billing

I have the new in-app billing (v3) system set up and working in an app. But now I want to know how it would all appear to someone in Europe that would want to purchase in Euro. Is this something to do with "mock locations" - or would that simply assume that I was on holiday and still give the price in my own currency?

**EDIT:** Thinking about it some more, I guess it could be the currency defined by the credit/debit card attached to your google account.